# MySQL Docker container create database if not exists

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to create a `Dockerfile` that will create an image that will have a MySQL 8.0 database on it.

Locally I will run my software against this MySQL container, but non-locally I will be running my software on AWS against a MySQL 8.0 RDS cluster.

So its important to me that if there are any RDS MySQL 8.0 "tunings", configurations or optimizations that will be applied automatically, that my local MySQL container mimic those as much as possible to prevent the "works locally but not in dev" symptom from rearing its head.

I'd like to be able to specify the directory on my machine where I want data stored and persisted across container runs. Ideally this would be passed in as a runtime argument so I could change it across runs if needed. When the container spins up I need it to run:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db;
```

Looking at the official [MySQL 8.0 Dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile) I have a few concerns:

```
FROM oraclelinux:7-slim

ARG MYSQL_SERVER_PACKAGE=mysql-community-server-minimal-8.0.23
ARG MYSQL_SHELL_PACKAGE=mysql-shell-8.0.22

# Install server
RUN yum install -y https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-minimal-release-el7.rpm \
      https://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el7.rpm \
  && yum-config-manager --enable mysql80-server-minimal \
  && yum install -y \
      $MYSQL_SERVER_PACKAGE \
      $MYSQL_SHELL_PACKAGE \
      libpwquality \
  && yum clean all \
  && mkdir /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
COPY healthcheck.sh /healthcheck.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
HEALTHCHECK CMD /healthcheck.sh
EXPOSE 3306 33060 33061
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

For one, I usually try to use Alpine Linux since it has a super small footprint. Is there any reason why I can't specify `alpine:latest` instead of `oraclelinux:7-slim`? Or is there something that MySQL *needs* that isn't available on Alpine? Are there any tunings/settings that exist on RDS MySQL that I need to be setting in here?

But the real question here is, **how would I add a way to connect to the running MySQL instance and run `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_db;` from inside this Dockerfile?**

Comment: Remember that the Dockerfile will get run only once and you'll re-run the image many times, as you note with multiple different volumes attached.  You can't manipulate the database as you suggest in the Dockerfile.  The `entrypoint.sh` script will get run every time the container starts up, though the stock MySQL image has a rather involved one; still, that's where it creates the initial database setup, on the attached volume, if it's not already configured.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze (+1) just to confirm `docker-entrypoint.sh` is a part of the MySQL Dockerfile distribution? If so, is it safe to assume that the `yum install` is what places it in my homedir? Also (and this is totally besides the point) what would the purpose of just renaming it to `entrypoint.sh` be?! Anyways, `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS` should be idempotent (it creates the DB once and only once), so unless you see a better way to go about it, I'm thinking just adding some way of modifying the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script?

Comment: And actually: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L134 could I just pass the name of `my_db` to this script somehow?